# function of the particle も in 「~も辞さない」

Tags: grammar, set-phrases, particle-も

I came across the sentence「訴訟も辞さない」in a book today and even though I am able to understand its meaning, I can't figure out the actual function of も in this case.

I looked into my grammar dictionary and the most satisfying definition I got was "も: a marker which indicates emphasis", but I'm not convinced it's the right one.

Should I just think it as a whole with 「辞さない」？　I know it's a phrase used to express one's willingness to do something, but is it used with any other particle ?

Thank you for you answers in advance.

Also, I can provide context if needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the も here is this:

> 1⃣ 係助詞 3-㋑動詞の連用形や動作性名詞に付き、打消しの語と呼応して、強い否定の意を表す。「思いもよらぬ話」「返事もしない」([デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/218351/meaning/m0u/))

So the も indicates emphasis, used with a negative phrase.

I think this も is usually translated as "even":

- 訴訟を辞さない wouldn't hesitate to file a lawsuit; willing to bring a lawsuit
- 訴訟**も**辞さない wouldn't **even** hesitate to file a lawsuit; willing to bring **even** a lawsuit

Answer (score 2):

The best way to translate も is as "even".

Some examples from the dictionary:
3 〔さえ〕
猿も木から落ちる
Even monkeys fall from trees occasionally.／Even an expert makes mistakes.／(Even) Homer sometimes nods.

彼はありがとうも言わずにそれを取った
He took it without so much as saying thank you.

http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/75042/meaning/m0u/%E3%82%82/