# 終わらなさそうだ versus 終わりそうもない

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between the following fragments?

> A: 終わらなさそうだ
>
> B: 終わりそうもない

It seems to me, both means "it does not look like it will finish".

If they are different, how to use each?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sentence A is closer to your translation. Sentence B is more emphatic and it sounds like you will be nowhere near the goal by the deadline.

`も + ない` indicates a strong negation (≒"never", "even"). See: [function of the particle も in 「~も辞さない」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40969/5010)

Comment: A is "objective", B is "emphatic".  But "objective" and "emphatic" are not always mutually exclusive.  Does your answer depend on the verb 終わる?  How about 雨は降りなさそう？

Comment: @CraigHicks Right. Maybe "matter-of-factly" would be the better word.

Comment: correction - 雨は降らなさそう

Answer (score 1):

A:終わらなそうだ
connotes objectivity.
The speaker isn't involved in or part of the deed.

B:終わりそうもない
connotes subjectivity.
The speaker is involved in or part of the deed.

Both are grammatically correct.
Hinges on speakers view on the deed.

Comment: How about 雨は降りなさそうだ vs. 雨は降りそうもない. Does this fit in that objective / subjective framework?

Comment: correction - 雨は降らなさそう

Comment: 降りそうもない implies that the speaker want it to rain.

Comment: What subjective expression would imply the speaker wants it not to rain?